# Nodejs.Mysql module is not installed

Tags: mysql, node.js

I tried to install the mysql module with npm. But when I run `npm install mysql`, I get the following error messages:

[image: **enter image description here**]

What do I have to do to properly install the module?

Comment: What type of errors are you getting and how you trying to install module ?

Comment: install it globally npm install -g mysql. If you have a package.json then install it with npm install mysql --save

Answer (score 0):

the error says that's you are not permission :

Run you Terminal as `Administrator` :

right click (on CMD) -> Run as Administrator

[image]

Comment: Can you set my answer as accepted answer and up vote it please

Comment: Excuse me, how to do this?

Comment: @Blackbonny in my anwser click one up arrow and click on ✓ mark